# Will passing of IntPtr as function's parameter cause memory leak?

Tags: c#, .net, f#

Let's say I have IntPtr variable, its value has been assigned via call of WinApi function (p/invoke). Then I passed that value in 10 different functions. Since IntPtr is struct (value type), each function will get a copy of the original variable. Will it cause memory leak? Should I close each copy of the original variable in each function?

```py
[DllImport("WinApiFunction")]
public static extern bool WinApiFunction(int arg1, int arg2, out IntPrt result)

public void Foo()
{
    var result = IntPtr.Zero;
    WinApiFunction(1, 2, out result);
    Foo1(result);
    Foo2(result);
    Foo3(result);

//...

    Foo10(result);
// ...

    CloseHandle(result);
}
```

Comment: May be.  It depends on the c++ code.  The Managed c# code will release most of the c++ resources, but cannot release resource that are allocated in the c++ that are not part of the execution stack. The c++ could be using Global Resources or Windows Allocated Memory which the c# code cannot release.

Answer (score 0):

`IntPtr` is often used as a place holder for handle or pointer values. It's hard to tell from the code exactly what is happening but copying a handle or pointer value wouldn't copy the underlying resource.

So in your example it seems correct to `CloseHandle` once. I would put it into a `try..finally` though to ensure that `CloseHandle` is always called if `WinApiFunction` returned a valid handle.

```
[DllImport("WinApiFunction")]
public static extern bool WinApiFunction(int arg1, int arg2, out IntPrt result)

public void Foo()
{
  var result = IntPtr.Zero;
  if (!WinApiFunction(1, 2, out result) || result == IntPtr.Zero)
  {
    throw new Exception("Oops");
  }
  try
  {
    Foo1(result);
    Foo2(result);
  }
  finally
  {
    CloseHandle(result);
  }
}
```

If you would build a proxy class around the handle this the use case to implement a finalizer (and IDisposable) on the proxy class.